# Change Zoom Key Bindings in Xfce

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, bind, zoom

In Xfce, you can use Alt + two fingers on the touchpad to zoom in and zoom out on the entire computer screen.

How can I change this zoom shortcut to instead use Alt + only one finger on the touchpad for zoom in and zoom out?

Comment: When you say "Alt + two fingers on the keypad", do you actually mean "touchpad" rather than "keypad"?

Comment: Yes! you are right. I can't believe I missed that. I mistakenly typed keypad. thanks very much. So I corrected my post to read....Alt + two fingers on the touchpad will zoom in and zoom out on  the entire computer screen.